# Calculate Beta and se from GWAS summary

Tags: gwas

I have some metaGWAS data which has only odds ratio and P values. Can I estimate standard error and effect size from these data?
(EX)
rsID     Allele1   Allele2   odds  P
rs12878  A         T         1.3   0.003

Comment: Can you format your question better, it is not clear right now what those numbers are. Also, given that you mention log odds, are these results from a logistic model? Do you have any other information except odds ratio and p-value?

Comment: Sorry for bad format. All information I have is 
rsID= rs12878
 Allele1=A Allele2=T (Allele1=Effect allele, Allele2=other allele)
odds ratio=1.3(not log(odds ratio)) 
Pvalue=0.003

Comment: I don't think it is possible.